# Razor Pages JsonResult doesn't serialize fields

Tags: razor-pages, jsonresult

Example:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string A;
}

public JsonResult OnPostTest()
{
    var a = new ClassA() { A = "test" };
    return new JsonResult(a);
}
```

How can I make the field A serialized automatically? I have a class with many fields which I need it to be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

System.Text.Json, the default serialiser, doesn't provide this capability - at least until .NET 5 is released: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/876

In the meantime, you can fall back to Json.NET and add the [JsonProperty attribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) to your field

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
```

Then

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

And

```
public class ClassA
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string A;
}
```